# Mate menu (Linux Mint 17) searches files when pressing enter - can this be changed?

Tags: search, mate-desktop, menu

Example: I press Supper button: menu opens. I write "fir": it shows Firefox, just like any launcher. I press Enter, it starts searching the whole system for files named "fir". I can avoid this by pressing down-arrow before Enter but I find this behavior odd and want to change it.

Comment: i don't think this is possible for now... but please place your question/suggestion here: https://github.com/linuxmint/mintmenu

Comment: @DJCrashdummy - https://github.com/linuxmint/mintmenu/issues/149

Comment: in [**Linux Mint 18**](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah_mate_whatsnew.php) (under the *Other improvements* section) this improvement was announced: ***"In mintmenu, pressing Enter after a search now launches the application placed at the top."***

Comment: @DJCrashdummy - I was expecting it to be fixed in LM 18 and I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintmenu/issues/149) that should be fixed by now.

It is yet present in Linux Mint 17.3, but was fixed in LM Mate 18 ([here](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah_mate_whatsnew.php): "*In mintmenu, pressing Enter after a search now launches the application placed at the top*."), just like in Ubuntu Mate 16.04, which comes with `mate-menu` version 5.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

For those who haven't upgraded to Linux Mint Mate 18, there is a fix to have the menu select the top entry in the search form. This worked for me on Mint Mate 17.3.

First, find the `applications.py` file that corresponds to your Mint menu:

```
$ locate applications.py
/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintMenu/plugins/applications.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/applications.py
```

On my system, the first result is the one.

Make a copy of this file to restore in case there are issues:

```
cd /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintMenu/plugins
sudo cp applications.py applications_backup.py
```

Next, find the following section in `applications.py`. For me, this started on line 862.

```
        for i in self.categoriesBox.get_children():
            i.released()
            i.set_relief( Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE )

        allButton = self.categoriesBox.get_children()[0];
        allButton.set_relief( Gtk.ReliefStyle.HALF )
        self.activeFilter = (0, text, widget)
```

Add `shownList[0].grab_focus()` after the loop:

```
        for i in self.categoriesBox.get_children():
            i.released()
            i.set_relief( Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE )

        shownList[0].grab_focus()
        allButton = self.categoriesBox.get_children()[0];
        allButton.set_relief( Gtk.ReliefStyle.HALF )
        self.activeFilter = (0, text, widget)
```

Either reboot or reload the panel. Then typing into the search bar from the menu will cause the first entry to be selected automatically for when you press enter.

[image]